# storing HTML/PHP files in database and using them as index/home page per user

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, web

Is there anyway to store web page in mySQL as a BLOB or anything?.. and using that webpage as the index/home page once a user logs in into the website?..

If you could also point me at a tutorial or at least a glimpse of a code that WOULD BE VERY MUCH APPRECIATED!!...

^_^

Comment: Are you looking to store the whole html page or just a section of content? If whole page what happens if design of the site changes?

Comment: Sounds like you'd be much better off using a templatesystem like Smarty or something similar. I see no good reasons for storing entire webpages in the database.

Comment: actually, im trying to change only a section of the content, i want something like a .php file to store the content in and then put it in the database to use it once a specific user logs in..

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a field type in MySQL called `BLOB`. You may use that field to store you page content. And on front end you may use some very cool `WYSIWYG` tools like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) .

[image]

Comment: I dont think nathan is looking at editing the content which is what CKEditor/TinyMCE would do. I think he wants his script to output the blob as the page content. e.g like a one page web application.